# Fragment not disappearing when I press back

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having an issue with my code in which I have a list of "Places" in a list fragment, I am selecting a Place and it is displaying a new fragment with that places details. I then click edit and it brings up a new fragment in which I can edit the details. After I click save, it goes to the details fragment but displays the new details. In all of these transitions to new fragments I add the previous fragment to the back stack so if I press back at any point it goes back and all of this works fine except if I press back after I've saved some new details, it displays the list of places but the new details fragment hasn't disappeared. Any ideas where I could be going wrong?

I've added code in button clicks and list fragment clicks that relates to fragment transitions as I think that is the only code relevant but if more is needed please let me know.

This piece is for when I select the Place from the list:

```
public void onListFragmentInteraction(Place place, Integer position) {

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    //replace the fragment currently in fragment container with the new details fragment.
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, details);
    //add the transaction to the back of the stack so the back button navigates back to list fragment
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
}
```

This part is where I click the edit details floating button:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.editPlace);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            //replace the fragment currently in fragment container with the new update fragment.
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, updatePlaceFragment);
            //add the transaction to the back of the stack so the back button navigates back to list fragment
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

And this part is where I click save and afterwards I press the back button to go back to the list and where my problem is occuring:

```
Button save = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.updateNewPlace);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            manager.popBackStack();
            manager.popBackStack();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            //replace the fragment currently in fragment container with the new update fragment.
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, placeDetails);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

I've been looking online for hours for solutions and I just can't work it out so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT

Just to clarify what fragments each interaction method is performed in:
The first is performed when an item in the list fragment is selected.
The second is held in the PlaceDetails fragment and clicking it takes you to a UpdatePlaceFragment fragment. The third button to save is held in UpdatePlaceFragment and is supposed to take you to PlaceDetails with the new details. Pressing back should then take you back to the list fragment, it does but the PlaceDetails is still visible. Strangely, if I select an item in the list and press back right away without editing, it goes to the list and the PlaceDetails fragment disappears.

EDIT 2:
I've updated the save button with the fixed code. Needed to add to the back stack and popBackStack twice. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How many placeDetails Fragments in backstack? how do you differentiate PlaceDetails which is calling from list and PlaceDetails which is calling after save button?

Comment: Just the one in the backstack once you save the details and I run popBackStack to clear that one out so the back button takes you to the list fragment. I haven't created a way to differentiate, would that help?

Comment: Are u sure you are calling addtobackstack method in save button click. Would u edit your code and update the question

Comment: I got it working in the end, I had to popBackStack twice to get back to the list though. I've updated the code to show it. Cheers for the help :)